# Mosfet Relay Gate Drive

Tags: mosfet, relay

Recently I ran into a part called a MOSFET Relay to address a [design problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/620703/port-expander-with-high-side-switch-ground-dilemma),
[image]

On paper, this part seems ok to use for my design but looking at the internal circuit I don't see any charge pump that drives the FET's gate. The Gate looks to be driven by [photodiode dome array (PDA)](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/MosfetE-book.pdf). Can this part be used to switch loads as it is? My [design requires an Isolated Load switch driven by an I2C Expander](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/620703/port-expander-with-high-side-switch-ground-dilemma), Can this part be used?

[Datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/408/TLP240A_datasheet_en_20200217-1102581.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of MOSFET SSR uses a series photovoltaic array with a circuit to speed (and ensure) turn off. The array supplies a number of volts but the current is weak so it takes some time to charge the gate capacitances (milliseconds, not microseconds or nanoseconds). On the plus side, you don’t need an external isolated supply to drive the gates.

If your circuit does not exceed the max voltage/current/isolation specs and can tolerate the leakage and on-resistance and the slow switching speed (3ms on/ 1ms off) then it should work okay.